# How I exclude more than one element with CSS selector group?

Tags: css

[In this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639238/how-to-select-all-inputs-except-type-value/64185023#64185023) the `:not(element)` is used to exclude one of all elements of group for add styles, but, if I need more than one element to exclude of the selection(Example: :not(p, a, [type="text"], ...) ), how do I do? I tried everythink but not does work =/

Comment: `:not(element):not(element1):not(element2)` ...

Comment: I tried this in https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_not but didn't work because of priority is low... wtf _-_"
If this don't have a tag or anythink to link, does't work well (didn't work with * too)